# How can I row bind the unmatch data in the column of first table from the second table

Tags: r

```
How can I row bind the not match data in the column of first table from the second table......


library(gtools)
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c"), number=c(4,3,2))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c", "k", "z"))


# fill in non-overlapping columns with NAs
df2[setdiff(names(df1), names(df2))] <- 0

rbind(df1, df2)
```

this the output in my code

```
a   number
1 a      4
2 b      3
3 c      2
4 a      0
5 b      0
6 c      0
7 k      0
8 z      0
```

the output i want..it will just add the not match data in the row of first table..

```
  a    number
1 a      4
2 b      3
3 c      2
4 k      0
5 z      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to left join `df2` and `df1` and replace `NA` with 0.

```
df3 <- merge(df2, df1, all.x = TRUE)
df3$number[is.na(df3$number)] <- 0
df3

#  a number
#1 a      4
#2 b      3
#3 c      2
#4 k      0
#5 z      0
```

Using `dplyr`, you could do the same by

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = "a") %>%
  mutate(number = replace(number, is.na(number), 0))
```

---

Or another option using `match`

```
df3 <- df2
df3$number <- df1$number[match(df2$a, df1$a)]
df3$number[is.na(df3$number)] <- 0
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c"), number=c(4,3,2))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c", "k", "z"))
```